# PHP-Mongo check if insert is successful

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there away to check if PHP-Mongo insert is successful?

something like

```
<?php

if ( $collection->insert($data) ) {
 //successful
}

?>
```

Comment: Depends on your write concern but if you write concern is `>0` then that method will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the PHP documentation for [Mongo Write Concerns](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php) is your friend.

If you want to check whether the row has been successfully written to disk (and into the journal), you could use something like this:

```
<?php
$options = array(
    "w" => 1,
    "j" => true,
);
try {
    $collection->insert($document, $options);
} catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
    /* handle the exception */
}
```

Comment: haven't tried if this will work but looking at it, I can tell it will. Thanks!